# Metagear effort_redistribute can't get it to do what I want

Tags: r, metadata

Anyone using Metagear for large meta anlysis data screening?

I'm trying to redistribute 1% of a large dataset with 2 reviewers, to new reviwer. Can easily redistribute 50:50, tried using effort = but keep getting errors with the string parameters (is it 99,1,0) or (98,1,1) etc. Tested using vignette code and example dataset and get the following....

```
    # load package
    library(metagear)

    # load a bibliographic dataset with the authors, titles, and abstracts of multiple study references
    data(example_references_metagear)

    #initialise refs
    theRefs <- effort_initialize(example_references_metagear)

    # randomly distribute screening effort to a team, but with Luc handeling      80% of the work
    theTeam <- c("Christina", "Luc")
    theRefs_unscreened <- effort_distribute(theRefs, reviewers = theTeam,    effort = c(20, 80))

    #results in christina with 2 papers, luc with 9

    #give a small amount of work to new reviewer, patsy 
    theRefs_Patsy <- effort_redistribute(theRefs_unscreened,
                                 reviewer = "Luc",
                                 remove_effort = "20", # move 20% of Luc's work to Patsy
                                 reviewers = c("Luc", "Patsy")) # team members loosing and picking

    #results in christina with the same 2 papers, luc with 5 and patsy with 4
    #shouldn't end up with chris 2, luc with 8, patsy with 2?
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the code as you have given it above will give you the following error

```
Error in remove_effort/(number_reviewers - 1) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

because `effort_redistribute` requires a numeric argument. Removing the quotation marks "" from around your percentage will solve the problem you are having with the vignette code and example dataset. You will end up with Christina having 2, Patsy having 2, and Luc having 7 (total of 11).

From what I understand of your question, it seems like you have a large dataset that is already distributed between 2 reviewers. You would initially distribute your dataset using code similar to this:

```
# load package
library(metagear)

# load a bibliographic dataset with the authors, titles, and abstracts of multiple study references
data(your_large_dataset)

#initialise refs
theRefs <- effort_initialize(your_large_dataset)

# randomly distribute screening effort to a team, with Reviewer1 and Reviewer2 equally sharing the work.
OriginalTeam <- c("Reviewer1", "Reviewer2")
theRefs_unscreened <- effort_distribute(theRefs, reviewers = OriginalTeam)
```

So far, we have the refs divided 50:50 between Reviewer1 and Reviewer2.

Now if you want to use `effort_redistribute` to assign 1% of the effort to a new reviewer, you have to chose whose effort is to be distributed, Reviewer1 or Reviewer2. In this example, I will remove from Reviewer1.

```
theRefs_New <- effort_redistribute(theRefs_unscreened, 
                                 reviewer = "Reviewer1",
                                 remove_effort = 1, # move 1% of Reviewer1's work to new reviewer, Reviewer3
                                 reviewers = c("Reviewer1", "Reviewer3")) # team members loosing and picking up work
```

This way you will end up with Reviewer1, Reviewer2, and Reviewer3 with 49%, 50%, and 1% of the effort, respectively. 
Alternatively, if you wanted to remove 0.5% effort from each Reviewer1 and Reviewer2 to give Reviewer 3 a total of 1% effort, you could use `effort_redistribute` twice in a row, to move 0.5% from each original review and assign it to the new one.

It would be easier to not have to redistribute at all, and assign the efforts 98:1:1 (or however else you want it) from the beginning when you use `effort_distribute`. Keep in mind that in order for it to work, the vector describing `reviewers` and the vector describing `effort` should be the same length.

`reviewers`: A vector of the names of each team member that will take on additional work.

`effort`: A vector of percentages used to allocate screening tasks among each team member. When not called explicitly, assumes effort to be distributed evenly among all members. Must be the same length as the number of team members, and also sum to 100.

```
Team_vector <- c("Reviewer1", "Reviewer2", "Reviewer3")
Effort_vector <- c(98, 1, 1)
theRefs_distributed <- effort_distribute(theRefs, reviewers = OriginalTeam, effort = Effort_vector)
```